# Comprehension of MICE package in R: influence of parameter maxit

Tags: r, mice

I have problems in understanding `maxit` parameter of the mice package:

```
library(mice)
data(nhanes)
str(nhanes)
imp = mice(nhanes, m=5, printFlag=FALSE, maxit = 30, seed=2525)
```

As described [here](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~dwarton/missingDataLab.html) I want to check the plausibility of the imputation results by considering the density plot `densityplot(imp)` (expecting similarity) and the convergence `plot(imp)` .

I know `plot(imp)` shows as lines all m Imputations (giving different results based on Gibbs Sampling) over the iterations (defined by `maxit`). When the trace lines reach a value and fluctuate slightly around it, convergence has been achieved ([from here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219013/how-do-the-number-of-imputations-the-maximum-iterations-affect-accuracy-in-mul/219049)). But how does the algorithm improve the predictive value in each Iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [MICE algorithm](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-FCS.html), from the book that one of the MICE authors wrote about using MICE. A detailed explanation is above my pay grade, but the gist is:

- Initially populate the missing values with random draws of non-missing values.
- Iterate (up to `maxit`):

  - For each variable:

    - Take draws of new and (hopefully) improved values, conditioned on this variable's observed data, current "complete"-by-imputation other variables' data, and a draw from the phi distribution (not sure about that part... I think it's the currently estimated distribution of the variable currently being imputed. Like I said, above my pay grade.).

Also, another section from the book, about [convergence](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-algoptions.html), which also discusses iterations and the order that the variables are visited for the imputation looping.

Reference: Flexible Imputation of Missing Data, Second Edition. 2018. Stef van Buuren.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! Could you please paste the references for the links you are providing in case they die in the future? Thanks!